# Postgres - pivot many rows - performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
create table myschema.mytable
(
    zone varchar(50),
    description varchar(50),
    amount double precision
);
```

I perform inserts like this (not the actual query, just to understand the data):

```
insert into myschema.mytable (zone, description, amount) 
values
  ('South', 'A1', 40),
  ('North', 'A1', 50),
  ....
  ('South', 'A2', 10),
  ('North', 'A2', 20),
  ('West', 'A2', 5);
```

In total I have like 500 records in that table (and the 4 zones); how can I perform a 'pivot' query to obtain something like this?

```
A1  A2  A3 .... Zone
---------------------
40  10   2      South
50  20   1      North
 0   5   3      West
```

My main issue here is the performance... I tried to do a series of left joins for each 'category' but it takes a lot of space in performance terms

Comment: Looks like the crosstab functions here are a good resource: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html I'd imagine that out-of-the-box pivot functionality would be your best bet in terms of performance.

Comment: Do you have an upper limit of the number of descriptions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, 14 descriptions

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional *aggregation* instead :

```
select zone, 
       sum(case when descr = 'A1' then amt else 0 end),
       sum(case when descr = 'A2' then amt else 0 end),
       sum(case when descr = 'A3' then amt else 0 end),
       . . .
from mytable t
group by zone;
```